# I'm trying to get a report about how many emails have gone through our exchange server today

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003

Is it possible to run a query or maybe some PowerShell command, which will show me the exact number of e-mails which have been gone through our Exchange server today and and exactly one week ago on the same day?
Our Exchange server's version is 2003 on a windows server 2003.

Comment: Have you tried looking in perfmon?

Comment: Yes, I have. Thank you for that, it helped me.
In addition, I've also checked the exchange log file and was able to find the exact number there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used perfmon with TotalMessages counter and it gave me the information i needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find this information in Perfmon and in your Exchange Message Tracking log files:

`Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\TransportRoles\Logs\MessageTracking`